# What does infoblox network applicance does

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp-server

My friend has given me [this](http://www.cnet.com/products/infoblox-1050-a-w-network-services-one-with-grid-dns-server-series/specs/#p=infoblox-1050-a-w-network-services-one-with-grid-dns-server-ib1050ans1grid/) network device. He doesn't know what to do with it. So far I only know that it is a DNS server.
So I want to learn from expert people in industry that can I use that device in home networking somewhere or it's a waste?
I'm not able to gather much information on  what it actually does and how it can be beneficial.

[This](http://www.computerlinks.ae/FMS/16234.infoblox_datasheet_hardware.pdf) was its specification. `Infoblox 1050`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.infoblox.com/products/dns-dhcp-services/grid

This is a DNS/DHCP server on steroids. "Grid" functionality of this server simplifies management across many similar devices across the network. If you have small network then there is almost no value for you in this product.